# getting the correct corner in my html display

Tags: html, css

so i am making a display in html. i have a nav bar i want to go down from the top left of the screen down and a bar of tabs to go from the nav bar to the other side of the screen. i currently have the bar of tabs going from the top left to top right and the nav bar going from the bottom of the tabs down. if i make the nav bar go from the top corner then the tabs go from the middle of the screen as oppose to running across the top.
basically i want it to look like this:
`_____++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
_ n  _+          tabs                                                          +
_ a  _++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
_ v  _
_    _
_    _`
instead of

`+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+                   tabs                                                        +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++_____
_  n_
_  a_
_  v_`

this is my code

```
<core-toolbar>
  <paper-tabs class="tabs" valueattr="name" selected="all" self-end>
    <paper-tab name="social" class="tab">SOCIAL</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab name="activity" class="tab">ACTIVITY</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab name="regularity" class="tab">REGULARITY</paper-tab>
  </paper-tabs>
</core-toolbar>
  <div class="navigation">
<div class="navTab">Results</div>
<div class="navTab">History</div>
<div class="navTab">Questions</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could place the div before the toolbar and then use `float:left;` on the div.

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="navTab">Results</div>
    <div class="navTab">History</div>
    <div class="navTab">Questions</div>
</div>
<core-toolbar>
    <paper-tabs class="tabs" valueattr="name" selected="all" self-end>
    <paper-tab name="social" class="tab">SOCIAL</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab name="activity" class="tab">ACTIVITY</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab name="regularity" class="tab">REGULARITY</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>
</core-toolbar>
```

CSS

```
.navigation {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: that results in nav tab starting in the middle of the screen as oppose to running along the top

Comment: Not unless you have some other styling already. Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4BVuD/)

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
<core-toolbar>
 <paper-tabs class="tabs" valueattr="name" selected="all" self-end>
  <paper-tab name="social" class="tab">SOCIAL</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab name="activity" class="tab">ACTIVITY</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab name="regularity" class="tab">REGULARITY</paper-tab>
 </paper-tabs>
</core-toolbar>
<div class="navigation" style="float: left;">
 <div class="navTab">Results</div>
 <div class="navTab">History</div>
 <div class="navTab">Questions</div>
</div>
```

I just added the `style="float: left;"`. No need to change anything.